# Prefilled the form data from the another page's input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to pass some data from one web page to another
 while clicking on the button.

**Blade Page:**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-7 info" style="padding-right: 35px;padding-top: 40px" >
          <h1 style="text-align: right;margin-bottom: 0px; font-style:italic;font-size:28px">"Wǒ bù zhīdào cóng nǎlǐ kāishǐ, píngtái bāng wǒ zhǎodàole zhīchí. Wǒ zhēn de hěn xǐhuān tāmen rúhé gēnjù wǒ de yùsuàn wèi wǒ tígōng duō zhǒng xuǎnzé bìng bāngzhù wǒ pínggū tāmen.</h1>
          <br>
          <p style="text-align:right; font-weight:bold; font-size:16px">Alvin R., Entrepreneur</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-5" style="padding-left: 35px;">
          <div class="card" style="border-radius: 20px !important;">
              <div class="card-head" style="text-align: center;font-weight: bold;padding-top: 25px;">
                  <header style="font-size: 25px;color: #3f9ae5;">GET STARTED</header>
              </div><!--end .card-head -->
              <div class="card-body" style="font-weight: bold;font-size: 16px;padding-left: 30px;">
                  <div class="form" style="padding-left: 15px;padding-right: 15px;">
                      <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-md-12">
                              <div class="form-group"  style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
                                  <select style="margin-top: 15px;font-size: 16px;" id="aops" class="form-control select2-list" name="areas">
                                  </select>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-md-12" id="req_options">
                              <div class="form-group">
                                  <select style="margin-top: 15px;color: grey;font-size: 16px;" id="request_type" class="form-control select2-list" name="request_types" >
                                  </select>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-md-12">
                              <div class="form-group">
                                  <input type="text" placeholder="Title " style="margin-top: 10px;padding-left: 10px;font-size: 16px;" class="form-control" name="title" id="title">
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <a href="submit_query"><button class="btn btn-theme effect standard btn-sm" id="post_request" style="background-color: #3f9ae5 !important;border-style: none;color:#ffffff;font-weight:bold;width: 100%;font-size: 16px">Post a Request</button></a>
                  <p style="font-size: 13px;padding-top: 24px;text-align: center;">By signing up you agree to the <a href="termsofuse"><u> terms of use</u></a> and <a href="privacypolicy"><u>privacy policy</u></a></p>
              </div><!--end .card-body -->
          </div><!--end .card -->
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have one simple template page where user can select two dependent drop-downs, AreaOfPractice and RequestsType and the other 'title' text filled, as user selects on the get started he will redirect to the new page where he will the requests filling form  with 5-6 fields wherein 3 fields would be prefilled with user's input from the previous page.

I have tried to do it with jQuery & Ajax.

```
  $.ajax({
            url:"getAops",
            type: "POST",
            data:{_token:csrf_token},
            success:function (result) {
                var options_grp = "";
                options_grp = "<option></option>";
                for(i=0;i<result.length;i++){
                    options_grp = options_grp + "<option  value='" +result[i].name+"_"+result[i].id+"'>"+result[i].name+"</option>"
                }
                $(options_grp).appendTo('#aops');
                $('#aops').select2({
                    placeholder: "Select Category *"
                });
            }
        });

        $('#aops').on('change',function () {
            $.ajax({
                url:"getRequestTypes",
                type: "POST",
                data:{_token:csrf_token,aop_id:$('#aops').val().split('_')[1]},
                success:function (result) {
                    $('#request_type').empty().trigger('change');
                    $('#req_options').css('display','block');
                    var options = "<option></option>";
                    for (var i = 0;i<result.length;i++){
                        options = options + "<option  value='" +result[i].name+"_"+result[i].id+"'>"+result[i].name+"</option>";
                    }
                    $(options).appendTo('#request_type');
                    $('#request_type').select2({
                        placeholder: "Select Request Type *"
                    })
                }
            });
        });
        $('#post_request').on('click', function () {
            var data = new FormData();
            if($('#aops').select2('data') != null){
                aop = $('#aops').select('data').text;

            }
            if($('#request_type').select('data') != null){
                request_type = $('#request_type').select2('data').text;
            }
            data.append("aop", $('#aops').val());
            data.append("request_type",$('#request_type').val());
            data.append("title",title);
            if(aop == "" || request_type == "" || title == "" ){
                show_notification("error","Please fill all required fields");
                return false;
            }else {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "createNewRequest",
                    type: "POST",
                    async: false,
                    data: data,
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                    },
                    success: function () {
                            $('#aops').html(aop);
                            $('#request_type').html(request_type);
                            $('#title').val(title);
                            return true;
                    },
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false
                });
            }

        });
```

Comment: use localStorage

Comment: @AshayMandwarya ,no idea bro, about the localstorage,i am new to front-end.

Comment: Refer the link    https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage.              You can set store information inside the browser only using this and can be retrieved on any page inside the same browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a basic example to the technique.
You can save many fields by making an object like {name-field:name-data,x-field:x-data} and so on. You can retrieve this on other page and set it to the form inputs.

```js
$("#setbutton").click(()=>localStorage.setItem("form-data",$("#set").val()))

$("#getbutton").click(()=>{
var data=localStorage.getItem("form-data")
$("#get").val(data);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="set"/>
<button id="setbutton">Set</button>
<br><br><br>
<input type="text" id="get"/>
<button id="getbutton">Get</button>
```

Comment: sdfgdsf
 Get
{
  "message": "Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': The document is sandboxed and lacks the 'allow-same-origin' flag.",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 18,
  "colno": 48
}          this is what i got when i run this code snippet

Comment: Run it in your browseror on fiddle. It wont work in the snippets due to the mentioned sandboxing.   https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: If you want to prefill the forms, get them as soon as the page loads not on button click. Try to get the element on document.ready

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){
                                                                                                                         
            var data=localStorage.getItem("form-data")
        if(data)
        $("#get").val(data);
        })`